# What is the best way to convert jar to mac app using a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, unix, jar, .app

Recently I had been trying to solve the problem of generating mac os `.app` from java `jar` file using maven plugin.

`appbundle-maven-plugin` is a popular plugin of doing this, but it doesn't work for M1 macs, as I've seen.

Then I came up with a very simple solution and created maven plugin that could generate mac `.app` with the structure below, with the ability to specify `jdk` and `jar`, other things as well, in plugin configs.

```
App.app
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── App
    ├── Resources
    │   ├── dock-icon.png
    │   └── icon.icns
    ├── app
    │   └── app.jar
    └── jdk
        ├── ...
```

The logic behind this structure is that `MacOS/App` is a unix executable, it contains shell script that says something like `java -jar app.jar` (simplified), it has 3 lines, basically it runs the specified jar file with java inside the specified jdk, that's it.

This works perfectly, from my point of view. As it is very very simple, I suspect it may have some problems that I can't see myself. Also `appbundle-maven-plugin` generates some complicated unix executable, not human readable, so it's not a shell script.

Moreover, I've seen some apps that are built with java, none of those apps use approach similar to mine, their unix executables doesn't contain a shell script when I look into them.

So questions are: Is this a good approach? What problems it has? Is it ok to use this in production? If not what is a better and more standard one? I can't get how other apps generate a unix executable they have, as it's not a shell script.

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, I will leave the link to the repo of maven plugin I've created. https://github.com/sandrojologua/jar2app-maven-plugin